# How to I output and sort classes in alphabetical order?

Tags: java

Okay so I have a full code here and currently working with a project demonstrating laptop.
How would I go about displaying the laptop classes (Dell, Acer etc) in "alphabetical order" when it outputs the lines?

Like, Acer opens in ... Dell opens in (should be in alphabetical order)

I'm stuck. I tried sort array functions but I just can't think of other ways.

I would really appreciate any help from you guys.

```
     public class LaptopProcessor
    {
      private static LaptopProcessor lp = new LaptopProcessor();
      private static LaptopGenerator lg = new LaptopGenerator();
      private static Laptop [] laptop = new Laptop[9];
      private static String[] LaptopOriginalCompare = new String[9] ;
      private static String[] LaptopTempoCompare = new String[9] ;
      private static int ctr;
      private static int ctrFrom;
      private static int ctrTo;
      private static boolean isTheSame;
      private static String brandName1;
      private static String brandName2;
      private static String time;

      private void populateLaptops(){
        /*populates all laptop attributes since laptop[ctr] is global */ 
        for(ctr=0; ctr<laptop.length ;ctr++){
           laptop[ctr] = lg.selectLaptopByNumber(ctr);
           //populate the time
        }

        /*just to get the class name*/
        for(ctr=0; ctr<laptop.length ;ctr++){
           Class c = laptop[ctr].getClass();
           System.out.println(c);
        }
      }

      private void selectAndcompareShutdownTime(){
         for(ctrFrom=0; ctrFrom < laptop.length ;ctrFrom++){
           for(ctrTo=0; ctrTo < laptop.length ;ctrTo++){
             /*here now you can compare there attributes*/
             if (ctrFrom != ctrTo){
                brandName1 = laptop[ctrFrom].showBrand();
                brandName2 = laptop[ctrTo].showBrand();
                time = laptop[ctrFrom].selectShutdownTime(); ///just get any of the two shutdown time just to output
                isTheSame = laptop[ctrFrom].selectShutdownTime().equalsIgnoreCase(laptop[ctrTo].selectShutdownTime());
                if (isTheSame){
                   System.out.println(brandName1 + " and " +brandName2+ " has the same shutdown time for " + time + ".");
                   System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------"); 
                   System.exit(0);
                }
             }   
           }
         }
      }  

      private void selectAndcompareRebootTime(){
        for(ctrFrom=0; ctrFrom < laptop.length ;ctrFrom++){
           for(ctrTo=0; ctrTo < laptop.length ;ctrTo++){
             /*here now you can compare there attributes*/
             if (ctrFrom != ctrTo){
                brandName1 = laptop[ctrFrom].showBrand();
                brandName2 = laptop[ctrTo].showBrand();
                time = laptop[ctrFrom].selectRebootTime(); ///just get any of the two shutdown time just to output
                isTheSame = laptop[ctrFrom].selectRebootTime().equalsIgnoreCase(laptop[ctrTo].selectRebootTime());
                if (isTheSame){
                   System.out.println(brandName1 + " and " +brandName2+ " has the same reboot time for " + time + ".");
                   System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                   System.exit(0);
                }
             }   
           }
         }
      }

      private void selectAndcompareOpenTime(){
        for(ctrFrom=0; ctrFrom < laptop.length ;ctrFrom++){
           for(ctrTo=0; ctrTo < laptop.length ;ctrTo++){
             /*here now you can compare there attributes*/
             if (ctrFrom != ctrTo){
                brandName1 = laptop[ctrFrom].showBrand();
                brandName2 = laptop[ctrTo].showBrand();
                time = laptop[ctrFrom].selectOpenTime(); ///just get any of the two shutdown time just to output
                isTheSame = laptop[ctrFrom].selectOpenTime().equalsIgnoreCase(laptop[ctrTo].selectOpenTime());
                if (isTheSame){
                   System.out.println(brandName1 + " and " +brandName2+ " has the same open time for " + time + ".");
                   System.out.println("------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                   System.exit(0);
                }
             }   
           }
         }
      }

      private void executeShutdown(){
        for(ctr=0; ctr < laptop.length ;ctr++){
           laptop[ctr].shutdown();    
        }
        selectAndcompareShutdownTime();
      }

      private void executeReboot(){
        for(ctr=0; ctr < laptop.length ;ctr++){
           laptop[ctr].reboot();
        }
        selectAndcompareRebootTime();
      }

      private void executeOpen(){
        for(ctr=0; ctr < laptop.length ;ctr++){
           laptop[ctr].open();
        }
        selectAndcompareOpenTime();
      }

      private void startProcess(){
        populateLaptops();
        System.out.println("");
       /*choose which laptop functions*/
       String strChoice = selectChoice();
        switch(Integer.parseInt(strChoice)){
          default: 
          case 1: executeOpen(); break;
          case 2: executeReboot(); break;
          case 3: executeShutdown(); break;
        }
      }

      private String selectChoice(){
         return javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("LAPTOP METHOD: \n [1] OPEN \n [2] REBOOT \n [3] SHUTDOWN");  
      }

      public static void main (String [] args){

          // static method is special because it can be called without first creating an object of the class in which the method is declared

          lp.startProcess();
      }
    }







    public class Acer extends Laptop{
        //ATTRIBUTES

        final String shutDownTime = "10000MS";
        final String rebootTime = "11000MS";
        final String openTime = "12000MS";
        private final String brandName = "ACER";    

        @Override
        public void shutdown() //method header. This prints.
        {
          System.out.println("SHUTDOWN ACER IN " + shutDownTime);
        }
        @Override
        public void reboot()
        {
           System.out.println("REBOOT ACER IN " + rebootTime);
        }
        @Override
        public void open(){
           System.out.println("OPEN ACER IN " + openTime);
        }
        @Override
        public String selectShutdownTime(){
            return shutDownTime;
        }
        @Override
        public String selectRebootTime(){
            return rebootTime;
        }
        @Override
        public String selectOpenTime(){
            return openTime;
        }
        @Override
        public String showBrand(){
            return brandName; 
        }        
    }


    public class LaptopGenerator
    {
      public Laptop selectLaptopByNumber(int id){
         switch(id){
           default:
           case 0: return new Msi();
           case 1: return new Dell();
           case 2: return new Toshiba();
           case 3: return new Acer();
           case 4: return new Asus();
           case 5: return new Lenovo();
           case 6: return new Samsung();
           case 7: return new Hp();
           case 8: return new Sony();     
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Make your Laptop class comparable, and sort the array.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Sorry I really don't want to discourage you but... what? I don't understand what you're asking and you're throwing a wall of code at us (half of it commented out). Please narrow your question down, edit and try to be more concise

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) for that

Example :

```
Set<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<String>();
     treeSet.add("somevalue");
     treeSet.add("Acer");
     treeSet.add("Samsung");
     treeSet.add("Apple");
     treeSet.add("Dell");
```

In the TreeSet the String will keep the natural order. If no convenient you can provide a comparator.

Comment: You missed "Lenovo" *flies away*